# Урал — в кавычках или нет?

Tags: ономастика, названия, кавычки, аббревиатуры

Автомобиль УРАЛ — нужны кавычки или нет?
УРАЛ — аббревиатура или условное название?
Как же правильно?

Comment: "Урал" - марка, как "Москвич", кавычки нужны.

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ

Comment: И не надо писать заглавными. Иначе точно получится аббревиатура.

Comment: Урал - это горы такие. А также географический регион, а также река. Конечно это не аббревиатура.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Аббревиатурные названия пишутся без кавычек: ЗИЛ, ВАЗ, УАЗ, КамАЗ.

См.: Академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина.

Comment: Урал - никак не аббревиатура

Comment: Аббревиатуры может и пишутся без кавычек, только с чего вы взяли, что Урал - это аббревиатура? Про Уральские горы не слышали? А про реку Урал?

Comment: Уральский автомобильный завод. Именно так написано на их сайте.

Comment: @Серж И что? УАЗ (Уральский Автомобильный Завод) - это аббревиатура, а Урал - нет.

Comment: При чем тут УАЗ? УАЗ ( Ульяновский автомобильный завод), а не уральский.

Comment: @Серж Хорошо, УАЗ ни при чем. Хотя это не отменяет того факта, что Урал - это не аббревиатура. А если это аббревиатура, то расшифруйте пожалуйста каждую букву этой якобы аббревиатуры? Кстати на их сайте написано АЗ Урал. АЗ - это аббревиатура. Урал - название. Зайдите в их раздел "О компании". Там написано: Автомобильный завод "Урал".

Answer (score 5):

Вот теория:

Названия марок автомобилей справочники рекомендуют писать в кавычках с прописной буквы: автомобили «Волга»,"Урал", «Вольво», «Ниссан», «Шкода», а названия самих автомобилей как технических изделий – со строчной буквы в кавычках (кроме названий, совпадающих с собственными именами – личными и географическими). Например: «кадиллак», «москвич», «тойота», «ниссан», но: «Волга», «Ока» (совпадают с именами собственными, поэтому пишутся с большой буквы). Исключения: «жигули», «мерседес» (совпадают с именами собственными, но пишутся со строчной).

Однако на практике различить, в каком случае наименование представляет собой название марки автомобиля, а в каком – наименование технического изделия, часто представляется затруднительным: Всем автомобилям он предпочитает «Тойоту» / «тойоту». В спорных случаях решение о написании с прописной или строчной буквы принимает автор текста.

2.1.  Названия, написанные латиницей, в кавычки не заключаются: автомобили Toyota Yaris, Peugeot 306, Daewoo Matiz,   Škoda Fabia, Lada Priora.
Неоднословные названия (марка и модель автомобиля), написанные кириллицей, пишутся через дефис, при этом все части наименования пишутся с прописной буквы: «Лада-Приора», «Тойота-Королла», «Рено-Меган», «Ниссан-Теана», «Хёндай-Гетц», «Ниссан-Альмера-Классик», «Сузуки-Гранд-Витара». Но: «Фольксваген-жук» (перекличка с нарицательным существительным).

2.2. Аббревиатурные названия  автомобилей пишутся без кавычек: ЗИЛ, ВАЗ, КамАЗ, BMW.

В бытовом употреблении названия средств передвижения пишутся без кавычек, например: Приехал на стареньком москвиче  (на роскошном кадиллаке). Без кавычек пишутся также разговорные названия машин с уменьшительно-ласкательными суффиксами, напр.: москвичок, фордик, уазик.

Comment: Людмила, но ведь в теории нет  Урала, а у вас почему-то есть.

Comment: Ну, это уже пример, а не теория, подставила, потому что он сюда как раз к месту, ведь это название автомобиля.

Comment: УРАЛ ( Уральский автомобильный завод) КАМАЗ ( Камский автомобильный завод), ЗИЛ ( Завод имени Лихачева). В чем разница?

Comment: Уральский автомобильный завод - это УралАЗ, а "Урал" - марка грузовых автомобилей.

Answer (score 1):

**Общая теория**

**1)  Прописная буква, без кавычек (в специальной литературе)**
    С прописной буквы без кавычек (форма 1) пишутся  названия  в технической литературе:

*Самолёт  Боинг-737 является самой распространенной моделью в мире.

Производство Ил-18 продолжалось с 1958 по 1970 годы.*

**2) Прописная буква с кавычками (основная форма)**
С прописной буквы с кавычками (форма 2) пишется большинство названий в этой группе:
самолет «Юнкерс-88», автомобили «Жигули», «Рено», космические корабли «Восток», «Аполлон», холодильники «Самсунг», «Минск», стиральная машина «Индезит».

*Летал на «Мессершмитте-109», на третьем боевом вылете был сбит над Кавказом.
Автомобили «Рено» вписали яркие страницы в историю мирового спорта.*

**3)  Строчная буква с кавычками**
При обозначении серии употребляется запись по форме 3 – строчная буква и  кавычки: «мессершмитт», «юнкерс», «боинг» (серии самолетов).

*Но повторного налета «мессершмитты» не сделали.

Гвардейцы сосредоточили огонь на «юнкерсах».

Мы вынуждены  летать на «боингах», чтобы интегрироваться в мировую авиацию.*

Comment: Вера, ***КамАз*** тоже встречается в кавычках.  Но такое употребление некорректно. И у Розенталя, и у Лопатина без кавычек. При этом нужно подчеркнуть, что автомобили «КАМАЗ » изготавливаются с использованием передовых технологий и материалов как отечественного, так и импортного производства.

Comment: Всё корректно, Серж, что разумно и имеет объяснение, некорректны только формальность в применении правил и неумение оценить реальную ситуацию. Из википедии: Первый автомобиль КамАЗ сошёл с главного сборочного конвейера 16 февраля 1976 года  (НАЗВАНИЕ АВТОМОБИЛЯ). По подсчетам специалистов, с начала выпуска автомобилей «КамАЗ» Советский Союз получил только от их эксплуатации около 8 млрд руб. транспортной прибыли (НАЗВАНИЕ СЕРИИ).

Comment: И название, и марка изделия пишется согласно правилам без кавычек.